# How can I work around deeply nested callbacks within NodeJS and sqlite-3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I've been getting to grips with node and node-sqlite3 and need to build a report up based on a number of queries:

```
var db = require('./db');

module.exports = {
  getActivity : function (user_id, done) {
    var report = {};

    db.get('SELECT * FROM warehouse WHERE user_id = ?', user_id, function (err, warehouse) {
      report.warehouse = warehouse;

      db.all('SELECT * FROM shops WHERE warehouse_id = ?', report.warehouse.id, function (err, shops) {
        report.shops = shops;
        return done(report);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

My goal was to be able to generate a report from a route and serialize it as a JSON response. Here's how my route looks:

```
app.get('/api/hello',
  auth.check,
  function(req, res) {
    hello.getActivity(1, function (data) {
      res.send(data);
    });
  });
```

I will most likely have more queries to include in this report and thus more nested callbacks. What options do I have to avoid this? I'm familiar with promises etc but node-sqlite doesn't have anything built in for cleaning this stuff up. Maybe I am using it incorrectly?

Last of all, I am passing in a 'done' callback from the route. Maybe this is the node way of doing things but it would be great if I could just simply return the report once it's generated, without the callback. Is there a better pattern for this?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a report engine built on node that has the same issues of multiple queries. To keep thinks clean, I use async, which is an awesome control flow library:
https://github.com/caolan/async#series

You will want to look at the async.series. It keeps your code a little cleaner than tons of embedded functions.

NOTE: You will need to create a reference to variables you need to access from one step to the next outside of the async.series context. For exaple I use the var one in function for two:

```
//keep context to shared values outside of the async function
var one,
   two;
async.series([
function(callback){
    // do some stuff ...
    one = 'one';
    callback(null, one);
},
function(callback){
    //!access value from previous step
    two = one + one;
    callback(null, two);
}
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
// results is now equal to ['one', 'oneone']
});
```

Comment: Also, using the done callback is definitely the node way of doing things, though I usually call it 'next'(a matter of preference). Its the heart and soul of asynchronous patterns. Someday you will be able to use 'yield', but honestly once you get used to node's async style, you start to love it.